# Setting a SAFARRAY output parameter in a COM method

Tags: c#, com, interop

I'm trying to study and reimplement a (black-box) COM server for an existing (black-box) client. I successfully [registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647679/how-to-register-a-net-assembly-in-place-of-an-existing-com-server/25662057#25662057) a dummy implementation by importing the type library and creating a .NET class that implements the interface of the server.

I have a problematic signature that does not seem to work when called by the client:

This is the IDL definition:

```
[id(0x00000007), helpstring("method GetFoo")]
HRESULT GetFoo(VARIANT* vector);
```

The imported .NET definition:

```
[DispId(7)]
void GetFoo(ref object vector);
```

Note: the `vector` parameter is an output parameter.

The client can successfully call my server which implements this interface. During this call I can see that the `vector` parameter contains an array of 16 bytes. However, it appears that the data I'm setting in the array is not correctly sent to the client. I have reverse engineered the original server and found the exact VARIANT flags that it expects for the paramter. Using this information I have created a C++ client that gets the data in the output paramter when calling the original server:

```
const int TABLE_LENGTH = 16;
SAFEARRAY* table = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_I1, 0, TABLE_LENGTH);

VARIANT val; VariantInit(&val);
val.vt = VT_BYREF | VT_ARRAY | VT_I1 | VT_NULL;
val.pparray = &table;
realServer->GetFoo(&val); 
// now table contains valid data
```

If I use this client to call my server, I get a `SafeArrayTypeMismatchException` *before* the breakpoint in the method would be hit.

My question is: how can I implement the .NET method so that a the above client would get the data I set in the `ref` parameter?

Comment: Have you tried to marsall it as an unmanaged type array?

Comment: @MikeofSST how can I do that? I can't change the .NET definition, it is from a generated interop assembly.

Comment: You could try: `IntPtr dataPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(16);`  Then dataPtr will be a handle to the array, which you can Marshal into a managed array if you need.  Note that the '16' is the same magic number you use in your question.

Comment: @MikeofSST Thanks. Still throws the same exception unfortunately.

Comment: Did you copy the client data from the `vector` to the unmanged memory at dataPtr?  I think Marshal.Copy() is the API to do that.

Comment: The client data is empty (zero bytes). Nevertheless, I tried copying the 16 zeros and call the function, but it's still not working.

Comment: Sounds like there may be some pre-requisite to calling the `GetFoo` API.  I've passed unmanged data back and forth to native COM components this way with no problem.  Not sure I can help much with the meaning of the exception message, sorry.

Comment: I'm replicating the previous calls from the real client (even with careful timing), so I'm leaning towards this being a marshaling issue, not something else.

Comment: Maybe try `Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);` to allocate the buffer in different memory?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a VARIANT to keep the server happy.  That is *object* in a .NET program.  So it has to look like this:

```
object arg = null;
realServer.GetFoo(ref arg);
byte[] data = (byte[])arg;
```

The IDL was poorly authored, the argument should have been attributed with [out, retval].  Usually a sign that you'll have some more problems.  Another problem with arrays is that they might have their first element at index 1 instead of 0.  Something you can see back in the debugger, the *arg* variable will look like `System.Byte[*]`.  In which case you'll have to cast to Array instead of byte[].

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately it does not seem to work this way either (in fact, this is one of the first variations I tried).

Comment: Hmya, common problem, SO users post the last and most wildly wrong version of the code they tried.  What's this business with trying to replace the server, why are you still making calls to the old server?  Do you have *any* code that ever made this call successfully?  Then show us.

Comment: @HansPassant It appears that the API requires the address of  a block of memory into which it can copy the `Foo` as its output.  If so then the memory must be of a sufficient size to hold the `Foo` and therefore it would be useful to know what `VT_` variant type should be behind the pointer.  The exception implies that some 'value' is incorrect, and having the content of `vector` as an output implies that the content of the memory is not at fault, but the value of the address may be.  Would the error message say "Value does not fall within the expected range" if the address were incorrect?

Comment: @HansPassant, the reason for reimplementing the server falls under my NDA, so I can't disclose it. The reason for making calls to the old server is to be able to study its behavior so the reimplemented version can mimic some of it. As explained in the post, the real client can successfully call my dummy server, but my test client can't call the real server. One clue might be the fact that upon getting the call in the dummy client, the parameter is not null but, but an array of 16 bytes. The code that successfully makes (or rather receives) the call is simply using the tlbimp-ed interface.

Comment: @MikeofSST, HansPassant, I have changed the question (still in the same context) and added substantial new information. If you have time, please take a look at it.

Comment: VT_ARRAY | VT_NULL is bizarre, you'll never convince the CLR to use that.  Write this code in C++/CLI instead so you can get the interop wrong the same way.

Comment: I know it is bizarre, but it is the exact value that I see as the operand of the CMP instruction in the debugger and this is the only combination of flags that worked so far. The original client is implemented in VB6 if that helps. Which code do you mean? The server?

Comment: Back to square one: you've got a very poorly authored COM component that needs a bizarre way to get called to be happy.  Very few reasonable options that I can think of but one: get rid of it.

Comment: @HansPassant That is not an option unfortunately. Do you think a custom marshaler might work? I tried implementing one and editing the IL of the interop assembly so that the interface uses it, but it does not seem to get called.